# Update already opened Excel workbook C#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I have excel document that gets updated frequently from sensors and external data sources.

In C# i am opening the file and doing work with the data. What do i need to do to update my sheet variable without trying to reopen the file again.

```
void test(){
    Application xlApp = new Application();
    excelBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
    Worksheet sheet = excelBook.Worksheets[sheetName];

    if (sheet != null){
       var r = sheet.UsedRange.Value2;

       while(true){
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r, Formatting.Indented);

            //do work with the json data here
            //........

            //make sure we have latest updated sheet
            //these are not working.

            excelBook.RefreshAll();
            excelBook.AutoUpdateSaveChanges = true;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Completely the wrong tool for the job.  Use a database and forget using Excel sheets.  Seriously.

Comment: i dont have the option. its either this or writing VB within excel..